# Cannot call a function in Javascript - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, electron, chart.js

I am developing an app with `electron` and `chart.js`.
I have connected a delete button located into an `HTML` file. When I press the button, the information is deleted in my `sqlite3` db like a charm. Then I press a second button to refresh my chart. Again it works like expected. I came with the idea of calling the refresh function from the delete function but my chart remains unchanged.

```
let myLabel = [];
let myValues = [];

function delData() {
    var data_firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;

    const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('./data.db');
    db.run(`DELETE FROM Info WHERE firstName = '${data_firstName}';`, function(err, row) {});
    db.close();
    refreshData();
}

function refreshData() {
    myLabel = [];
    myValues = [];

    const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('./data.db');
    db.each('SELECT firstName, age FROM Info;', function(err, row) {
        myLabel.push(row.firstName);
        myValues.push(row.age);
    });
    db.close();
    popChart(myLabel, myValues);
}

function popChart (myLabel, myValues) {

    if (typeof testChart !== 'undefined') {
        testChart.destroy();
    }

    let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    testChart = new Chart(myChart, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: myLabel,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Age',
                data: myValues,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(84, 103, 180, 0.69)'
            }]
        },
        options: {}
    });
}
```

Comment: try to call `refreshData` from the callback function in `run`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `delData` function is not waiting to delete the item from the database before calling the `refreshData` function, use:

```
function delData() {
  var data_firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;

  const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
  let db = new sqlite3.Database('./data.db');
  db.run(`DELETE FROM Info WHERE firstName = '${data_firstName}';`, function(err, row) {
    db.close();
    refreshData();
  });
}
```

So the refresh will run after the delete.

You can achieve the same results using ES6 async/await:

```
async function delData() {
  var data_firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;

  const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
  let db = new sqlite3.Database('./data.db');
  await db.run(`DELETE FROM Info WHERE firstName = '${data_firstName}';`);
  db.close();
  refreshData();
}
```

This will wait until the db command complete, then continue the execution.